# Direction of gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, metric-tensor, geodesics

General Relativity explains the path a falling body makes (ex. An apple falling toward the center of the Earth) as a geodesic in curved spacetime. What explains the direction the apple falls? In other words: why doesn't the apple follow the same geodesic away from the Earth? What provides the kinetic energy in the "downward" direction?

Answer (score 2):

1. For a given timelike [geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) that would be the direction that points into the [future light-cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone) in spacetime.
2. The geodesic itself depends (besides on the [geodesic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity)) on conditions, such as e.g., [initial conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_condition) or boundary conditions.

Comment: This answer seems incomplete, since when I toss an apple upward it also follows a timelike geodesic into the forward light-cone, but one that for awhile heads away from the Earth. Am I missing something?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Could the direction of travel along the geodesic be determined by Entropy (i.e. The Second Law of thermodynamics)? Or do we need a theory of quantum gravity to provide gravitrons to explain why gravity is attractive and not repulsive?